# My Apache setup alongside IIS

Tags: apache, iis, windows-vista

I am trying to learn PHP.  I am having trouble getting Apache working correctly on my Vista Home Premium machine.

I have IIS7 running and I would like to have Apache running along with it.  I was looking around on the web and some say that it would be fine having the two together as long as they are looking at different ports.

I left IIS looking listening on port 80 and I edited the httpd.conf file in the apache2triad/conf folder to listen on port 8080 and changed the server name to localhost:8080. When I go to localhost:8080/phpmyadmin the page that allows me to create a database looks like all the page styling is off so I know that something is already wonky.

I enter a database name and click the Create button, then receive a 404 error from IIS. It says that it is looking for a file at:

Requested URL:
http://localhost:80/phpmyadmin/db_create.php

Physical Path:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpmyadmin\db_create.php

It's pointing to my inetpub folder but all of my PHP stuff is in the c:\apache2triad folder.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a URL from your Apache server, you need to use port 8080 instead of port 80 (which is where you say IIS is running) - so your URL should be http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/db_create.php

As Shawn said, if you're not familiar with apache at all, you're probably better off setting up PHP under IIS - see http://www.php.net/install.windows